# Regex [\S but not [[\S?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get matches of single bracket followed by a non-space, but not a double-bracket and non-space.

```
Aka:  This is ok:  [s
      This should be skipped:  [[s
```

I have `@"\[[\S^\[]"` but it isn't quite working.

**Edit**: To clarify a little, I'm working on a wiki parser (so it is string based - I had thought that was only what regular expressions worked on).  My links start with [, but I'd like to escape [ with a double [[.  The wiki already works, but I'm creating a revised version that is (hopefully) easier to extend.

Here's the Handler invoke code:

```
foreach (Rule rule in rules)
{
    if (position + rule.Length > text.Length)
        break;
    if ((rule.PreCondition & condition) == rule.PreCondition)
    {
        if (substring.Length < rule.Length)
            substring = text.Substring(position, rule.Length);
        if (rule.Pattern.IsMatch(substring))
        {
            string previous = text.Substring(0, position);
            sb.Append(previous);
            text = text.Remove(0, position);
            position = 0;
            text = rule.Handler(new HandlerParameter(text, condition, previous));
        }
    }
}
```

So the BracketHandler uses the pattern to determine if we're at a bracket.  My original pattern was `\[\S`, but that doesn't work for [[s if it is checking the [s and the last character of previous is a [.  Just a heads up with my convoluted code, but at least it is posted to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could use a negative lookbehind:

```
@"(?<!\[)\[[^[\s]"
```

(Wow that looks sinister, eh?...)

Edit: a potential alternative which doesn't require a lookbehind:

```
@"(^|[^[])\[[^[\s]"
```

Comment: That looks like perl, so yes, yes it does :)

Comment: Thank you this works for some cases, but not everything.  I ended up pre-parsing for double brackets first.  A question, would the lookbehind be slower, is that why the other?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the ^ has to be at the begining of the group to indicate a negation.  Why not indicate the negative group of spaces and '[' like this:

```
@"\[[^\s\[]"
```

Comment: This works, but only from the start of the string—so it depends whether or not the OP is searching a string or not.

Comment: \s is any space, \S us any non-space.  Still that isn't working, as it qualifies the [s of [[s.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something here, or `[^[]\[[^\s[]` will work without problems?

Comment: This has the opposite problem of juharr's solution: it won't match if [s appears at the start of the string.